# Difference between fun1 and fun1() in python

Tags: python-3.x

**I can't understand the difference**

```
class Student():#code is in python
    leaveday=8
    students=90

mashh=Student
rohan=Student
print(rohan.leaveday)
mashh.leaveday=12
print(rohan.leaveday)
print(mashh.leaveday)
print(Student.leaveday)
```

and how is this possible that class variable changed

```
class Student:
    leaveday=8
    students=90

mashh=Student()
rohan=Student()
print(rohan.leaveday)
mashh.leaveday=12
print(rohan.leaveday)
print(mashh.leaveday)
print(Student.leaveday)
```

somebody explain it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`class attributes`, like the ones you have defined, are always equal across all instances of the class because they always refer to the same variable.

In fact, you don't even need to have an instantiated object to check its value, as you have seen in your code:

```
print(Student.leaveday)
```

Python is not statically typed, but everything has a type. And in your case, if you check your types you could confirm that `mashh=Student` and `mashh=Student()` are two very different things.

```
mashh=Student
```

Is just making an "alias" for the class `Student`, another way of calling that pre-existing class

```
mashh=Student()
```

Is instantiating the `Student` class, making an object that is saved in the `mashh` variable.

What you're probably looking for are `instance attributes`. You can read up on the difference between class attributes & instance attributes online, e.g. 
https://www.python-course.eu/python3_class_and_instance_attributes.php